# Steht vor einem Firmennamen ein Artikel, wenn die Rechtsform weggelassen wird?

Tags: article, definite-article, brand-name

**Beispiel**

Nehmen wir an, die Firma heißt *Buntstifte KG*, aber in diesen Sätzen wurde ihre Rechtsform weggelassen. Sollte jetzt vor dem Firmennamen ein Artikel stehen?

> Buntstifte ist eines der führenden Unternehmen auf dem Markt.
>   Die Produkte von Buntstifte sind immer von höchster Qualität.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deine Beispiele sind richtig. Dort darf kein Artikel stehen. Weiterführend sei gesagt, das selbst wenn dort eine Rechtsform steht, empfohlen wird, diese zu ignorieren:

> Treten Abkürzungen wie AG, GmbH, KG, e. V. in einer Firmenbezeichnung o. Ä. auf, handelt es sich gewöhnlich um Appositionen. Genus und Numerus der Firmenbezeichnung richten sich dann nicht nach der Apposition, sondern nach dem Zweitglied der Firmenbezeichnung, z. B.: An das Euro-Kreditinstitut AG (Zweitglied: das Institut) und nicht: An die Euro-Kreditinstitut AG mit falschem Bezug auf AG (die Aktiengesellschaft). Liegt jedoch der Nachdruck auf der betreffenden Gesellschaftsform (AG, GmbH usw.), dann richten sich Genus und Numerus des Firmennamens nach dieser; sie sollte dann ausgeschrieben werden: An die Aktiengesellschaft Hüttenwerk Oberhausen; die Produktion der Dichtungsring-Gesellschaft mbH.

© Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch, 7. Aufl. Mannheim 2011

Wenn Du allerdings gerne einen Artikel nutzen möchtest, wäre das in folgender Form möglich:

> Die Produkte der Firma Bunstifte sind immer von höchster Qualität.

Oder auch mit voller Bezeichnung

> Die Produkte der Firma Bunstifte KG sind immer von höchster Qualität.

Abschließend lässt sich die von Konstruktion auch gänzlich vermeiden:

> Buntstifte Produkte sind immer von höchster Qualität.

Comment: Beim konkreten Beispiel aus der Frage würde ich *dringend* dazu raten, entweder den Begriff "Firma* voranzustellen oder die Rechtsform anzuhängen, weil sonst gegebenenfalls nicht klar ist, dass es sich um einen Firmennamen und nicht um eine Produktbezeichnung handelt.

Comment: Der Firmenname mit der Rechtsform wird am Anfang des Textes erwähnt. Bleistifte KG (nachfolgend: "Bleistifte")

Answer (score 4):

Das kommt darauf an. Zur Einführung schon einmal die Zusammenfassung (aus Fahlbusch/Nübling 2014: 252; Hervorhebungen ergänzt):

[image]

Banken und Versicherungen sind im Allgemeinen feminin und haben einen festen (~ bestimmten) Artikel (dazu näher Fahlbusch/Nübling 2014: 271ff). Auch Fluggesellschaften sind produktiv feminin, hier schwankt der Artikelgebrauch aber stärker (Fahlbusch/Nübling 2014: 274f). Bei Unternehmen (Mischkonzernen) allgemein verhält es sich teilweise ähnlich: Neben einem Bestand an maskulinen und neutralen Firmennamen ist heute im Wesentlichen nur noch das feminine Genus produktiv (Fahlbusch/Nübling 2014: 280ff); zugleich unterbleibt der Artikelgebrauch aber meistens:

> "Es wird offensichtlich, dass die Unternehmensnamen hauptsächlich ohne
>   Artikel beziehungsweise mit entsprechenden Ausweichkonstruktionen
>   verwendet werden, um sich nicht auf ein bestimmtes Genus festlegen zu
>   müssen." (Fahlbusch/Nübling 2014: 282)

Man beachte, dass Unternehmen, deren Name einem Personennamen entspricht, von dieser Betrachtung ausgenommen sind, weil sich in diesem Fall das Artikelverhalten regional unterscheidet. Nübling (2015: 319) - übrigens eine der führenden Forscherinnen auf dem Gebiet der Eigennamen - weist auf die Existenz einer "sog. Artikelgrenze" hin, die einen südlichen Teil Deutschlands (der in diesen Fällen zum Artikelgebrauch tendiert oder diesen sogar als obligatorisch betrachtet) von einem nördlichen (mit weit geringerer Neigung zum Artikelgebrauch) trennt. Diese Artikelgrenze "schreitet von Süden nach Norden voran, d. h. Personennamen werden zunehmend mit Artikel verwendet" (ibid.).

Eine eindeutige Antwort kann man auf die Frage also nicht geben: **Überwiegend wird kein Artikel verwendet, bei Personennamen gibt es regionale Unterschiede.**

---

<sup>Literatur: Fahlbusch/Nübling (2014), Der Schauinsland – die Mobiliar – das Turm: Das
referentielle Genus bei Eigennamen und seine Genese, Beiträge zur Namenforschung 49(3), 245–288 (frei verfügbar via [germanistik.uni-mainz.de](https://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/files/2018/06/Fahlbusch-N%C3%BCbling-2014-Namengenus.pdf)); Nübling (2015), Die Bismarck – der Arena – das Adler: Vom Drei-Genus- zum Sechs-Klassen-System bei Eigennamen im Deutschen, Zeitschrift für germanistische Linguistik 43(2), 306-344, https://doi.org/10.1515/zgl-2015-0016.</sup>

Comment: Gibt es einen Weg, den Artikel Nübling 2015 einzusehen, ohne dem Verlag de Gruyter dafür gleich ein Vermögen zu überweisen? - 30 Euro für einen germanistischen Aufsatz... die haben eine Meise...

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann [Ja!](https://www.germanistik.uni-mainz.de/files/2018/06/N%C3%BCbling-2015-classifier-ZGL.pdf)