# Artikel: Namen der Fluggesellschaften im Deutschen

Tags: article

Sind die Namen der Fluglinien im Deutschen tatsächlich feminin? Die Lufthansa, die Virgin, die Thai, die Condor, die Eurowings - stimmt es so? Ohne Ausnahmen?

Vielen Dank!

Comment: Hast du dir schon mal [Die Liste der Fluggesellschaften in DE](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Fluggesellschaften_in_Deutschland) angesehen? Da Gesellschaft feminin ist, halte ich es fuer sehr wahrscheinlich, jedoch gab es da mal den (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_Flugdienst)[BMW Flugdienst]

Comment: Zur Frage ob Gesellschaftsformen von Firmen eine Rolle spielen sollten, gab's schon einmal diese Frage: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/55291/steht-vor-einem-firmennamen-ein-artikel-wenn-die-rechtsform-weggelassen-wird/55293#55293

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die kurze Antwort lautet: 
**Nein, nicht ausnahmslos jede Fluggesellschaft trägt einen femininen Namen.**

Die Annahme ist naheliegend, dass die Namen von Fluggesellschaften feminin sind, weil die meisten tatsächlich als (die) *Gesellschaft* feminin firmieren.

Die [Liste der Fluggesellschaften in Deutschland](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_Fluggesellschaften_in_Deutschland) gibt Aufschluss und zeigt, dass es mit dem [BMW Flugdienst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMW_Flugdienst) auch welche mit männlichem Namen gibt.

Hingegen ist die [Condor Flugdienst GmbH](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condor_Flugdienst) weiblich, da das weibliche *GmbH* Teil ihres Namens ist.

Comment: Der [Nürnberger Flugdienst](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BCrnberger_Flugdienst) existiert zwar nicht mehr, war aber deutlich größer.

Comment: Clijsters, vielen Dank! Wie sieht es mit den Namen ausländischer Fluggesellschaften aus, z.B. "Qantas"?

Comment: Ich denke auch hier hat der "Erfinder" des Namen das letzte Wort. Einerseits duerfte es eine Rolle spielen, ob die Sprache ein Geschlecht fuer die Firmierung vorsieht oder ob unsere Uebersetzung ein passendes hat. So wuerde ich einen _flight service_ z.B. maennlich ansprechen, da es dem deutschen Flugdienst entspricht.